# Backbone render placement

Tags: backbone.js

Just wondering why this works:

```
window.NewListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<a href="/list" class="button new-list">Create New List</a>'),

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});

window.List = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "": "index" },

  initialize: function(){
    this.newListView = new NewListView();
  },

  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
  },

  index: function(){
    $('.lists').append(this.newListView.render().el);
  }
}));

$(function(){ List.start(); })
```

And this doesn't:

```
window.NewListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<a href="/list" class="button new-list">Create New List</a>'),

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});

window.List = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "": "index" },

  initialize: function(){
    this.newListView = new NewListView();
    $('.lists').append(this.newListView.render().el);
  },

  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
  },

  index: function(){

  }
}));

$(function(){ List.start(); })
```

The difference is just moving

```
$('.lists').append(this.newListView.render().el);
```

between initialize() and index() of the router.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because of the way, and when, you're creating an instance of your router.

When you do:

```
window.List = new (Backbone.Router.extend({...
```

You're creating an instance of the router before the DOM is loaded.  Therefore, in your `initialize` function, your jQuery selector is not returning any nodes.

If you open up a console, you can see the order of operations logged to it on this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/x64hw/

```
window.NewListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<a href="/list" class="button new-list">Create New List</a>'),

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});

window.List = new (Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "": "index" },

  initialize: function(){
    this.newListView = new NewListView();
    console.log("List Initialize");
    $('.lists').append(this.newListView.render().el);
  },

  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
  },

  index: function(){

  }
}));

$(function(){ 
    console.log("Before List Start");
    List.start(); 
    console.log("After List Start");

})​
```

Results in:

```
List Initialize
Before List Start
After List Start
```

But, if you create your router instance after the DOM loads:

```
window.NewListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template('<a href="/list" class="button new-list">Create New List</a>'),

  render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});

window.List = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: { "": "index" },

  initialize: function(){
    this.newListView = new NewListView();
    console.log("List Initialize");
    $('.lists').append(this.newListView.render().el);
  },

  start: function(){
    Backbone.history.start();
  },

  index: function(){

  }
});

$(function(){ 
    console.log("Before List Start");
    list = new List();                
    list.start(); 
    console.log("After List Start");

})​
```

The order is as you would expect, and it works:

```
Before List Start
List Initialize
After List Start
```

as shown in this jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/eDWfh/